# What am I doing wrong in creating this dynamically generated table?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, html-table, dynamically-generated

Apologies for any simple mistakes, this is my first Stack Overflow post and I'm relatively new to coding.

I am attempting to create a website that displays a dynamically generated table using DOM elements. This table's rows and columns have been defined using DOM elements, and it should now populate itself on page load when storeItemOutput() is called from initialize(). It should be pulling the data from a loop through the previously defined and populated array storeItems, and displaying their attributes in the table id "storeItemOutput". It should also get one of five values from a dropdown box, and display items that match the selected category whenever it is changed.

However, I can't get the table itself or it's contents to actually display on the page. I'm unsure what is preventing this, and the lack of any output has left me stumped. Am I missing some code in my function? Is the table not created properly?

I've included parts of my code below, as well as expected output and actual output to try and help you understand my issue.

```html
<select class="categoryDropDown" style="margin: 30px;">
  <p>
    <option selected value="All" onload="storeItemOutput();">All</option>
    <option value="Tops" onchange="storeItemOutput();">Tops</option>
    <option value="Bottoms" onchange="storeItemOutput();">Bottoms</option>
    <option value="Shoes" onchange="storeItemOutput();">Shoes</option>
    <option value="Accessories" onchange="storeItemOutput();">Accessories</option>
  </p>
</select>

<table id="storeItemOutput">
  <span><strong>| ID | Product Name | Price | Qty | Max | Category | Image |</strong></span>
  </br>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>b</th>
      <th>b</th>
      <th>b</th>
      <th>b</th>
      <th>b</th>
      <th>b</th>
      <th>b</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>b</td>
      <td>b</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  (Output all store items via DOM table here)
</table>
```

This is some of my HTML code with an ID'd dummy table, and a dropdown menu class.

```js
var storeItems = [];

function StoreItem(id, name, price, qtyOnHand, maxPerCust, category, shipping, reviews, description, image) {
  this.id = id; //String
  this.name = name; //String
  this.price = price; //Number
  this.qtyOnHand = qtyOnHand; //Number
  this.maxPerCust = maxPerCust; //Number
  this.category = category; //String
  this.shipping = shipping; //Number
  this.reviews = reviews; //Array
  this.description = description; //String
  this.image = image; //String
}

storeItems.push(new StoreItem("Y2k111", "Black Hoodie", 119.99, 10, 1, "Tops", 19.99, this.reviews, "100% Cotton Hoodie in Black", "/img/home_img/link"));
```

Some Javascript code of creating an empty array for store items, creating an object constructor for store items, and pushing a new item to the array (normally there is more than one item being pushed, I used just one here to save space).

```js
function storeItemOutput() {
  var itemTableDiv = document.getElementById("cartItemOutput");
  var table = document.createElement("table");

  itemTableDiv.innerHTML = "";

  document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].remove();

  var tBody = document.createElement("tbody");

  var headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  var hC1 = document.createElement("th");
  var hC2 = document.createElement("th");
  var hC3 = document.createElement("th");
  var hC4 = document.createElement("th");
  var hC5 = document.createElement("th");
  var hC6 = document.createElement("th");
  var hC7 = document.createElement("th");

  hC1.innerHTML = "Item ID";
  hC2.innerHTML = "Item Name";
  hC3.innerHTML = "Item Price";
  hC4.innerHTML = "Item Quantity";
  hC5.innerHTML = "Max Items Per Customer";
  hC6.innerHTML = "Category";
  hC7.innerHTML = "Image";

  headerRow.appendChild(hC1);
  headerRow.appendChild(hC2);
  headerRow.appendChild(hC3);
  headerRow.appendChild(hC4);
  headerRow.appendChild(hC5);
  headerRow.appendChild(hC6);
  headerRow.appendChild(hC7);

  tbody.appendChild(headerRow);

  for (var index = 0; index < storeItems.length; index++) {
    var products = storeItems[i];

    var theRow = document.createElement("tr");

    var c1 = document.createElement("td");
    var c2 = document.createElement("td");
    var c3 = document.createElement("td");
    var c4 = document.createElement("td");
    var c5 = document.createElement("td");
    var c6 = document.createElement("td");
    var c7 = document.createElement("td");

    c1.innerHTML = products.id;
    c2.innerHTML = products.name;
    c3.innerHTML = "$" + products.price.toFixed(2);
    c4.innerHTML = products.qtyOnHand;
    c5.innerHTML = products.maxPerCust;
    c6.innerHTML = products.category;
    c7.innerHTML = products.image;

    theRow.appendChild(c1);
    theRow.appendChild(c2);
    theRow.appendChild(c3);
    theRow.appendChild(c4);
    theRow.appendChild(c5);
    theRow.appendChild(c6);
    theRow.appendChild(c7);

    tbody.appendChild(theRow);
  }
  itemTableDiv.appendChild(tbody);

  var selectedCategory = document.getElementByClass("categoryDropDown").value;
  var filteredItems = [];
  var index = 0;
  while (index < storeItems.length) {
    if (storeItems[index].category == selectedCategory) {
      filteredItems.push(storeItems[index]);
    }

    index++;
  }

  storeItemOutput(filteredItems);
```

And finally, my function that is meant to create and populate the table, before displaying the items that match the selected category.

Here is an image of what the table should look like:

[working table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lINU.png)

And the lack of output for my table:

[my missing table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgpT2.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Span is not a child of table.

Comment: OK, upon review I've realized that I don't need the span for the table anyway, as the header rows should be created using DOM. As such, the spans are gone now. Anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example. A few things worthy of mention:

- I've used a template element, since it makes repeatedly creating
  similar content very much faster.
- Floating-point math has rounding errors. For this reason, I've stored the
  prices in cents rather than dollars. Perform all math on the number
  of cents, then present it as dollars & cents
- A NodeList is very similar to, but slightly different than an array. It does not for instance have a `forEach` member function. For this reason, I used `Array.from` in the appendRow function. (which is actually shorter by 1 line if you use the commented code instead)

```js
"use strict";

function newEl(tag) {
  return document.createElement(tag)
}

function byId(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id)
}

function qs(sel, parent = document) {
  return parent.querySelector(sel)
}

function qsa(sel, parent = document) {
  return parent.querySelectorAll(sel)
}
window.addEventListener('load', onLoaded, false);

function onLoaded(evt) {
  var tableData = [
    ["PID01", "Fluffy Bear", 599, 600, 20, "Toy", "bear.png"],
    ["PID02", "Rubber Ducky", 1599, 40, 5, "Toy", "duck.png"],
    ["PID03", "Cool Handbag", 599, 1, 2, "Fashion", "bag.png"],
    ["PID04", "Fidget Spinner", 999, 120, 10, "Toy", "spinner.png"],
    ["PID05", "Lame Handbag", 4599, 60, 3, "Fashion", "bag.png"],
    ["PID06", "UltraMega Genuine Laptop", 170599, 20, 2, "Technology", "laptop.png"],
  ];
  populateTable(tableData);

  var categoryNames = ["All", "Fashion", "Toy", "Technology"];
  populateSelect(byId('catSelector'), categoryNames);

  qs('select').addEventListener('change', updateFilter, false);
}

function populateSelect(selElem, data) {
  selElem.innerHTML = '';
  data.forEach(txt => selElem.appendChild(new Option(txt, txt)));
}

function populateTable(data) {
  data.forEach(appendRow);

  function appendRow(itemData, itemIndex, items) {
    let newRow = byId('productRowTemplate').content.cloneNode(true);
    let cells = Array.from(newRow.firstChild.cells);
    cells.forEach((cell, index) => {
      if (index == 2)
        cell.textContent = '$' + (itemData[index] / 100).toFixed(2);
      else
        cell.textContent = itemData[index];
    });
    //      cells[0].textContent = itemData[0];
    //      cells[1].textContent = itemData[1];
    //      cells[2].textContent = '$'+(itemData[2]/100).toFixed(2);
    //      cells[3].textContent = itemData[3];
    //      cells[4].textContent = itemData[4];
    //      cells[5].textContent = itemData[5];
    byId('storeItemOutput').tBodies[0].appendChild(newRow);
  }
}

function updateFilter() {
  let filter = byId('catSelector').value;
  let prodRows = qsa('#storeItemOutput > tbody > tr');

  if (filter == 'All') {
    prodRows.forEach(row => row.classList.remove('notShown'));
  } else {
    prodRows.forEach(
      row => {
        if (row.cells[5].textContent == filter)
          row.classList.remove('notShown');
        else
          row.classList.add('notShown');
      }
    );
  }
}
```

```css
.notShown {
  display: none;
}

.price,
.qty,
.max {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<template id='productRowTemplate'><tr>
        <td class='id'></td>
        <td class='name'></td>
        <td class='price'></td>
        <td class='qty'></td>
        <td class='max'></td>
        <td class='cat'></td>
        <td><img class='icon'/></td>
    </tr></template>

<body>
  Filter:
  <select id='catSelector'></select>
  <table id='storeItemOutput'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Qty</th>
        <th>Max</th>
        <th>Category</th>
        <th>Image</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```